# How do I simply read a .txt file that I created and count its lines

Tags: java, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I am very new with Android Studio, but I have two questions.

So, currently I am using a method to take the lines from a .txt file and convert it into an ArrayList.  I am using FileReader and LineNumberReader.  When I run the program, the catches are activated even though this code works on Eclipse.

My question:
1. I am currently storing the .txt file in the raw folder in assets.  Is this the correct place to put it?
2. The location I am using is "\res\raw\city.txt",  am I calling the file wrong?

Here is my code (*in Android Studio*) for some more context:

```
    //Method to take a file and convert into an ArrayList
    private ArrayList<String> txtArray(String fileLoc) throws IOException {
        int n = 22;

        File file = new File(fileLoc);

        //Counts how many lines are in the system
        try {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(fileLoc);
            LineNumberReader lr = new LineNumberReader(fr);

            lr.skip(Long.MAX_VALUE);
            n = lr.getLineNumber();

            Toast errorToast3 = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "the Number of lines is " + n, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            errorToast3.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast errorToast5 = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Fuk " + n, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            errorToast5.show();
        }

        Toast errorToast3 = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Still ok here " + n, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        errorToast3.show();

        //Takes lines from the text file and converts into Array List
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(new File(fileLoc));

        Toast errorToast7 = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Pls work " + n, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        errorToast7.show();

        ArrayList<String> test = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            test.add(kb.nextLine());
            //kb.next();
        }

        return test;
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

1. You probably want [internal storage](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage).
2. The path seems wrong, as it's using wrong slashes and also uses absolute path (starting with `/`). Try `res/raw/city.txt`.

Also you can look into [Files.lines().collect(Collectors.toList())](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-)

Comment: Thank you for the help! Is the assets folder a part of the internal storage?  If so, I tried using File file = new File(getContext.getFilesDir(), fileLoc);  Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work.